# Azure AD B2C SSO Technical Profiles, How to retrieve claims?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am having a problem when utilizing SSO.

When I have a user that signs in with the SignupSignin policy they are given a proper JWT token. If the user initiates a login with the ProfileEdit policy and signs in they are also able to successfully. However, if they sign in with the SignupSignin policy and then they go to the ProfileEdit policy they are being thrown an error.

The error message I am getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in technical profile "ReadCommerceData"

I have also looked at the Exceptions in IEF for the corresponding correlation Id and am only given a generic message: Exception Message:An internal error has occurred., CorrelationID:9b5310f5-919b-4846-9d85-d47999cd1bc7

```
       <TechnicalProfile Id="ReadCommerceData">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_BusinessAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_BusinessAddress2" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_BusinessCity" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Businessstate" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_BusinessPostalCode" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_BusinessCountry" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_AccountType" DefaultValue="consumer" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_streetAddress2" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The Expected outcome is that the user gets automatically signed in and able to edit their profile with no error.

I have read the Azure AD B2C documentation on [SSO technical profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso) but it is not very clear on how to retrieve values or ensure that it is working.

I have tried adding an OutputClaim to the SM-AAD Technical Profile. 
I have tried removing the  element from the ReadCommerceData technical profile.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your policies?

Comment: Hi Alfredo, the policies include a lot of proprietary data. Can you please specify what you are looking for exactly and I will gladly sanitize them and post for your review.

Comment: Basically both RP and their base policies (usually TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml and TrustFrameworkBase.xml). Are the later common to both RP? Have you enabled [app insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights) and looked into using the correlationId?.

Comment: Alfredo, yes I have posted the correlation ID in the problem above. Application Insights has not shed any light into this at all. Like I mentioned, there is a lot of proprietary data, I would be happy to share with you on an individual basis but not publicly.

Comment: Can you share your SSO configuration? It should be set in your technical profile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior

Comment: @Razi, this is for a custom policy and not a flow.

Comment: @ChristopherNorris For custom policy same information can be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior-custom-policy. Also, may be you also want to open a support ticket with Microsoft Azure team to avoid PII data disclosure on this public forum. You can always update answer with the resolution so community can benefit from it.

Comment: @ChristopherNorris if you cannot strip out the PII then as Razi suggested you would need to open a support ticket.

Comment: @Alfredo, I would love to. Do you have recommendations on the pathing I should use? The last time I opened a MS ticket regarding IEF it took about 2 weeks to get assigned to the right department.